# How to programatically create the users and roles in WSO2 API manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 API manager 3.1.0 I want to create the users and roles programatically. Are there any REST APIs available for the carbon console of the APIM to achieve this? I referred to this document
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/next/develop/product-apis/restful-apis/ which has only details of the
REST APIs available for API publisher and devportal mainly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RemoteUserStoreManagerService` SOAP service.

See https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs

Comment: I want to use only APIM. The above link is for the Identity server. We can use only apim for creating and managing the users is not it? or is it mandatory to use the IS for user management?

Comment: This service is there in APIM too

Comment: Only SOAP API is available for user management but no REST API is available?

Comment: Yes, APIM only has a SOAP service. IS has the SCIM REST API.

Comment: Thanks Bee. Is it possible to directly update the data base tables instead of using the SOAP APIs. If I am creating the Roles directly in the database table UM_ROLE will it work or are there any associated database tables also need to be updated?